# psi term error in fitting segmented regression in R

Tags: r

I am trying to fit the following segmented regression model using the "segmented" package in R.

```
lin.mod.1a <- lm(WTM[Treatment=="A"]~RE[Treatment=="A"])
seg.mod.1a <- segmented(lin.mod.1a,seg.Z=~RE[Treatment=="A"],psi=2)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in segmented.lm(lin.mod.1a, seg.Z = ~RE[Treatment == "A"], psi = 2) : 
  'psi' should be a list with more than one covariate in `seg.Z
```

I have not had any problem fitting a segmented model when the Treatment term is not defined, but I really want to fit the model when Treatment=="A". I understand what this error is saying but I am not sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `seg.Z` section of the help page for `?segmented`:

> Currently, formulas involving functions, such as `seg.Z=~log(x1)` or
>   `seg.Z=~sqrt(x1)`, or selection operators, such as `seg.Z=~d[,"x1"]` or `seg.Z=~d$x1`, are not allowed.

So it sounds like you should subset your data before trying this method

```
WTM.a <- WTM[Treatment=="A"]
RE.a <- RE[Treatment=="A"]
lin.mod.1a <- lm(WTM.a~RE.a)
seg.mod.1a <- segmented(lin.mod.1a,seg.Z=~RE.a,psi=2)
```